# Why does padding affect whether or not a background image shows up?

Tags: html, css, background-image, padding

I'm trying to build a simple responsive design. At this point, I'm just battling with the header. I'd like to have a background image in the header, and as the screen size gets bigger, a different image to appear in its place. Right now I just want to get the **iPhone 5/SE** screen size to work. The HTML has a simple `div`:

```
<div class="header"></div>
```

And I am including the viewport meta tag everyone's talking about:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

CSS has the following:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .header {
    padding: 5em;
    background: url(images/header-320.png) no-repeat top left;
    background-size: contain;
  }
}
```

When I remove the padding setting, the image disappears. If I set the padding to anything less than 5em, it adds a space between the right side of the image and the right side of the screen.

- Can anyone explain this behavior, and why (it seems that) the padding
  setting is necessary for the image to even appear?
- If it is absolutely necessary for some reason, do I always have to set it to some arbitrary value like 5em (which I found through experimentation as opposed to any kind of logic)?
- Maybe there's a clever workaround solution that I should use instead?

P.S.: this is for an eBay template, so I need to be able to do this without any JavaScript (they don't allow it).

Comment: In short: your .header element is empty and by default an empty div is rendered with height zero. A padding increases the height of an element because it's how the [box-model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Box_model) works.

Comment: @fcalderan thank you, that makes sense! So is that the solution then, to experimentally find a padding that allows the entire image to fit?

Comment: one step back: why do you need to have an empty element with a background? Does the image a) convey any information or b) is it for decorative purpose only? In case a) use a regular img, in case b) set a specific height or min-height

Comment: @fcalderan well, a bit of both... It's the company logo on a pretty background.. Eventually I want to add phone number and address on there as well and make those clickable, but I figured I'd keep things simple for version 1.

Comment: You could also give your empty div a width and height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Without padding/height

Take the below example:

```js
console.log(`Header height: ${header.clientHeight}px`);
```

```css
#header {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
```

I have set the `#header` element to have a `background-color: red`, but you can't see any red colour, right? Because the element's height is `0px` by default, so the element is *essentially not visible*.

## With padding/height

Now see this example with padding:

```js
console.log(`Header height: ${header.clientHeight}px`);
```

```css
#header {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
```

Notice the height is now `160px`, and you can see a big pile of red.

## To answer your question

> Can anyone explain this behavior, and why (it seems that) the padding setting is necessary for the image to even appear?

Padding is not necessary. But the height of an element is.

To give height to an element, you can either:

- Set `height`
- Set `padding-top` and/or `padding-bottom`
- Give HTML content (with height) to the element (i.e. texts, `img`s)

> If it is absolutely necessary for some reason, do I always have to set it to some arbitrary value like 5em (which I found through experimentation as opposed to any kind of logic)?

No. Read above.

> Maybe there's a clever work-around solution that I should use instead?

No. Read above.

**PS**

By default, elements with default `display: block` will have a default `width: 100%`, but no default height value. That is why you can see the border span 100% in width but `0px` in height.

Comment: Got it, thank you! Setting the height of the header explicitly in CSS seems to solve it. I'll try the other solutions you mentioned as well. Any advice as far as comprehensive tutorials on CSS?

Comment: As mentioned by [@Christian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5006588/christian-santos), [MDN's tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS) is great but it can be a bit overwhelming for beginners. You can try [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/) if you prefer a easier and straightforward (though poorly regarded among developers) tutorial.

Comment: Thanks! W3Schools stuff seems to help to figure out small things when I get stuck, but isn't really working for me as a tutorial. The MDN one is actually surprisingly well-written (I thought it was more a reference, before you or someone else pointed to their tutorial section), so I've been following that.

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone explain this behavior, and why (it seems that) the padding setting is necessary for the image to even appear?

As mentioned in the comments by @fcalderan, your `div` by default has no content and no styles, so it will have zero height. When adding padding (or explicitly giving it a `height`), the container will have a positive height and will display your image.

> If it is absolutely necessary for some reason, do I always have to set it to some arbitrary value like 5em (which I found through experimentation as opposed to any kind of logic)?

It's not arbitrary -- it depends on the dimensions of your image **and** the CSS styles that you choose. In your example, you've setting a `background-size: contain`, which "Scales the image as large as possible without cropping or stretching the image."

This ultimately means that if your container is proportionally wider than the background image, it won't stretch to fit the container, so you have to choose units that are proportional to the size of the image. In this case, your image seems to be `320px` wide, so setting `5em` equates to `80px` (5 * `16px`), which is 320 / 4 -- thus proportional to the image, so you won't see any whitespace.

If you do want the image to stretch to its container, try `background-size: 100%`, which should stretch the image to its container regardless of the proportions.

> Maybe there's a clever work-around solution that I should use instead?

No workaround needed -- it's just a matter of choosing the correct CSS styles to get the desired effect.

---

Further reading:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Box_model
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: Thank you, makes sense! Any advice as far as a comprehensive tutorial/guide for learning CSS properly?

Comment: I really like MDN guides for everything web related -- here's the CSS guide: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS